# how fix the error arrising "Method or data member not found" in Ms access VBA code 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I m making a school Management system software on Access 2007, but while in combo box i had made a province list and next box city i had written the cities names, i m connecting them with vba code than province name is selected the related cities are shown in that such box,but i got an error of "method or data member not found"...

I already tried to enable macros but issue didnt resolved

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub 'ProvinceID_AfterUpdate'()
Me.City.RowSource = "SELECT CityName FROM" & _
        " City WHERE ProvinceID = " & Me.ProvinceID & _
        "Order BY ProvinceID"
Me.City = Me.City.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a space after FROM in city.rowsource, and before "Order by ProvinceID"

Comment: can u type that for me , i didnt understand

Comment: But It highlights the Me.ProvinceId and says that method or member data not found

Comment: Why do you have surrounding `'`'s here: `ProvinceID_AfterUpdate`? Please remove them. Did you try to compile the code (you find that in the `Debug` menu)?

Comment: Compiler is not working its non selectable option

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Me.City.RowSource = "SELECT CityName FROM City " & _
    "WHERE ProvinceID = " & Me.ProvinceID & " " & _
    "ORDER BY City"
```

Comment: Then a field name is either missing or misspelled. Double-check.